# Rentals to "expats only" in Copenhagen Denmark

Tags: rental, housing, denmark

Many apartments in Copenhagen say "expat only". Yet the lease term appears as 1-2 years, which seems to be a standard length lease, also on many of the unrestricted apartments. Does anyone know why this restriction exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it often means slightly more than just expats, it means "expats who are backed by a large company". The reasons are probably: Increased willingness to pay high rents, and less likelihood to take the landlord to court over rent disputes.